# "Array index is less than one" error at Winbugs

Tags: arrays, arraylist, indexoutofboundsexception, winbugs14

I am working on a multilevel differential item functioning model using WinBUGS package. I have successfully built simpler models, but I have also gotten the error "array index is less than one". I'd be very pleased if you could help.

```
    # Model
    Model
    {
    for (l in 1:50){
    y[l] ~ dbern(p[l])
    logit(p[l])<- u2[stu[l]] - beta[x[l]] + gamma[tea[l], x[l]]*grp[l] + alpha1[x[l]]*geo[l] +
    alpha2[x[l]]*conf[l] + alpha3[x[l]]*ses[l]
    }
    for (t in 1:10){
    for (i in 1:10){
    gamma[t,i] ~ dnorm(gamma.hat[t,i], tau.gamma[i])
    gamma.hat[t,i]<-pi1[i] + pi2[i]*inq[t]
    }
    }
    # fixed effect prior
    for (i in 1:10){
    beta[i] ~ dnorm(0, .0001)
    alpha1[i] ~ dnorm(0, .0001)
    alpha2[i] ~ dnorm(0, .0001)
    alpha3[i] ~ dnorm(0, .0001)
    pi1[i] ~ dnorm(0, .0001)
    pi2[i] ~ dnorm(0, .0001)
    }
    # Random effect prior
    for (s in 1:5){
    u2[s] ~ dnorm(0,tau.u2)
    }
    tau.u2 <- pow(sigma.u2, -2)
    sigma.u2 ~ dunif (0, 100)
    for (i in 1:10){
    tau.gamma[i] <- pow(sigma.gamma[i],-2)
    sigma.gamma[i] ~ dunif(0,100)
    }
    }

   # Data
   list(y=c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0), ses=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), conf=c(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), geo=c(1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), grp=c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1), inq=c(1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2), stu=c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0), tea=c( 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), x=c(3, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2))


    #Initital values
     list(beta=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), alpha1=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),    alpha2=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),  alpha3=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), sigma.gamma=(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), u2=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), pi0=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), pi1=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), sigma.u2=1, gamma=structure(
.Data=c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), .Dim=c(10, 10)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indexes start from 1, not 0, in BUGS.  The variables `stu` and `tea` are used for indexing, but they take the values 0,1 - they should be 1,2 instead.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I have corrected this error notice and than I come across another error code (undefined real result error). I have shared in the link below.
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/120669/undefined-real-result-error-at-winbugs
I would be very pleased if you could help.

Comment: Answered there.  Could you mark this one as answered?

Answer (score 1):

Something going on with `x`. It is one shorter in length than the other variables, perhaps you are missing an observation.

Comment: Thanks Gjabel, I changed the variable x, but I have the same error code.